# Magento 2 message manager not working on product page

Tags: magento2, cache, messages

I have an issue where add to cart error is not appearing on the product page because the whole page was cached. once i disabled the cache then the validation is working fine.

i also tried to edit

vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

```
        <container name="page.messages" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="page messages">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="ajax.message.placeholder" template="Magento_Theme::html/messages.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Messages" name="messages" as="messages" template="Magento_Theme::messages.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
        </container>
```

this partially fixed the issue but still has some bugs. because sometime the messages appears and sometimes it doesnt.

anyone has an idea how to fix this? on other pages message manager is working fine. not sure why its like this on the product page. whats the best way to make this work?